# Schengen visa for a US born Baby

Tags: visas, schengen

Me and my husband are non-us citizen and applying for Schengen visa.
Our daughter (U.S Citizen) will be travelling with us.
So the question I have is when appearing for visa, do I need to show an airline reservation for her as well?

Update: I am paying a travel agent to provide itinerary for us for visa purposes, since I dont want to buy airline tickets etc before we get a visa.

Comment: As an USA citizen she does not need a visa, but I think that when you tell the visa officer that you bring your baby, they would be surprised if you do not have an airline reservation for her. They know she does need a ticket, and will take your application more serious if you can show it.

Comment: The baby may not need a ticket per se, if under age 2, but does need to be on the airline records. They now keep track of lap children. And she does need a passport.

Comment: @Willeke: Babies can travel as "lap infants", which doesn't need a ticket but is recorded on one of the parents's tickets.  (There's usually a small fee for this.)  For flights from the US to Europe, the airline will need to verify that the baby is with both parents or has permission anyway.

Answer (score 3):

As a US citizen your daughter wouldn't need to apply for a Schengen visa for a stay of less than 90 days. Therefore you don't need to mention her on your application.